# Threading profile for one endpoint in Mule results in endless hanging when used for two endpoints

Tags: threadpool, endpoint, mule-studio

I added a program to a Mule project in order to avoid duplication of code. They are both REST, access the same webservice and return json. The first service's threading profile looked like this:

```
 <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
    <default-receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="10" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" threadWaitTimeout="10000" maxBufferSize="100" maxThreadsIdle="2" >
 </configuration>
```

When I added my second service, the same threading profile caused the program to hang endlessly. No log entries, no nothing. Raising max active threads to 1000, or even deleting the WAIT option doesn't do anything. It's only when I change "maxThreadsIdle" to 3 or higher, or delete maxBufferSize or delete the entire thing that both can work in the same project. One other thing...when I edit the mule flow and save, the program automatically launches again. Oddly enough, the results end up appearing in any browser I left hanging from trying to submit.

What I want to know is why the min threads needs to be set to 3 or higher...I mean what the heck is actually going on here? Ideally, I would like to keep the threading configuration set to what I have here.

Comment: So... what's the question? Be more specific about what you need help with.

Comment: hah sorry. didnt even realize i didnt ask anything